# Issue while using different scoring metric in Gridsearchcv sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am doing elastic-net regression and trying to estimate the best hyper-parameter using GridSearchCV. But when I change scoring in GridSearchCV from default r2 to mean_squared_error, GridSearchCV makes every feature coefficient 0. I don't know why it is happening.

Here is the code.

```
param={
'elastic__alpha':np.linspace(.1,1,15),
'elastic__l1_ratio':np.linspace(0,1,30)
}
pipe=Pipeline([('scalar',StandardScaler()),('elastic',ElasticNet(max_iter=10000))])
search=GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=param,cv=4,scoring=make_scorer(mean_squared_error))
search.fit(train_x,train_y)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? Currently your code can not be run, since "train_x" and "train_y" are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You get this problem from the wrong use of the function `make_scorer` . By default it assumes that a greater score is better, if you look at the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html), under the argument `greater_is_better` :

> greater_is_better bool, default=True Whether score_func is a score
> function (default), meaning high is good, or a loss function, meaning
> low is good. In the latter case, the scorer object will sign-flip the
> outcome of the score_func.

If you are using r2, the default works. If you use mean squared error, you want to minimize the error and you need to set `greater_is_better = False`.

We can use an example dataset to demonstrate this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, mean_squared_error
from sklearn import datasets

data = datasets.load_boston()
X = data['data']
y = data['target']
```

Then set up some simple params:

```
param={
'elastic__alpha':np.linspace(0.2,0.8,2),
'elastic__l1_ratio':np.linspace(0.2,0.8,2)
}

pipe=Pipeline([('scalar',StandardScaler()),('elastic',ElasticNet(max_iter=10000))])
search=GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=param,cv=4,scoring="r2")
search.fit(X_train,y_train)

search.best_params_
{'elastic__alpha': 0.2, 'elastic__l1_ratio': 0.2}
```

Run your function:

```
pipe=Pipeline([('scalar',StandardScaler()),('elastic',ElasticNet(max_iter=10000))])
search=GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=param,cv=4,scoring=make_scorer(mean_squared_error))
search.fit(X_train,y_train)

search.best_params_
{'elastic__alpha': 0.8, 'elastic__l1_ratio': 0.2}
```

The best param is different and you can see the parameter with the maximum mean squared error is chosen:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(search.cv_results_['params'])
res['score'] = search.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
res.sort_values('score',ascending=False)

elastic__alpha  elastic__l1_ratio   score
2   0.8 0.2 30.348081
3   0.8 0.8 29.191112
1   0.2 0.8 25.891039
0   0.2 0.2 25.733661
```

If we do `greater_is_better=False` the result makes sense:

```
pipe=Pipeline([('scalar',StandardScaler()),('elastic',ElasticNet(max_iter=10000))])
search=GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=param,cv=4,scoring=make_scorer(mean_squared_error,greater_is_better=False))
search.fit(X_train,y_train)

search.best_params_

{'elastic__alpha': 0.2, 'elastic__l1_ratio': 0.2}

res = pd.DataFrame(search.cv_results_['params'])
res['score'] = search.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
res.sort_values('score',ascending=False)

    elastic__alpha  elastic__l1_ratio   score
0   0.2 0.2 -25.733661
1   0.2 0.8 -25.891039
3   0.8 0.8 -29.191112
2   0.8 0.2 -30.348081
```

So there's a good reason they provided an option called ‘neg_mean_squared_error’ and if we use this you will see you get the same results.